# Dynamic Distribution Groups

Tags: exchange-2010

I created several Dynamic Distribution Groups in EMC. It went fine. However, on the DC in ADUC they show up broken with a non-existent icon and no properties inside. Did I miss a step somehow? Exchange 2010 and Server 2008 R2 AD.

Comment: I don't have official documentation to back this up but I consider this normal. ADUC does not display those sames properties so it _appears_ broken. EMC knows what those objects are.

Comment: I don't really think that's how it goes. I used to have it working just fine but it seems broken now. I was using these groups for GPO assignment and now it's no longer working.

Comment: Hmmm... I only use them for mail (which they work fine for) so I am used to what I see (which is the same as you) as I expect nothing more. Would have to look into this more then. How did you use them for GPO? There membership lists are determined when they are used for distros.... it is not something that is stored IIRC

Comment: The groups were used in the Security Filtering section in the Group Policy Management for certain GPOs. So let's say I have a dynamic group of people with a mailbox in a certain OU. I want a GPO to apply to them, so I set that in the Security Filtering and it used to work just fine. Normally the Security Filtering defaults to Authenticated Users but you can set it to other groups or users.